# how to make table of sale that sale for then one item in one transaction mysql

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

Is there a way to make a column that can have multiple value of id from one table. I want to create a transaction table where user can buy multiple items in one transaction receipt. Iam using MySQL

this is how my current table are

tbl_transaction

```
id_transaction int auto_increment
id_customer int
product (i dont know the type?)
total_transaction varchar(20)
```

tbl_product

```
id_product int auto_increment
product_name varchar(40)
price varchar(20)
```

so when a customer choose one or more item the id_product can be save in product from table tbl_transaction

Comment: Sorry but its really not clear what you are asking here

Comment: One obvious mistake, a price really ought to be a numeric type and not a varchar

Comment: Another probably mistale, `total_transaction` again should be numeric but in fact it probably should **not exist atall**. If you want to know the total value of a transaction, run a query to calculate it, then it will always be accurate. Storing totals in a table allows for the possibility for that total to not be maintained somewhere

Comment: I get the feeling you are trying to fight against the proper way of storing data in a relational database. If a sale includes multiple items, store multiple rows, one for each product.